# Prevent page refresh on asp page when calling an ajax function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, cross-domain

Hello I got a problem which I can not solve for myself.
In an asp page after click on a button which call a JS function that calls an Ajax function. It ever refresh the page, I tried almost everything but I can not deal with it.
Here is the code:

ASP button:

```
<button id="btnNext" class="button" style="float: left;" onClick="return nextButton();">Next <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward" style="text-align: right;"></span></button>
```

JS functions:

```
       function apiCall() {
            if (!doNotDisplay) {
                url = getURL();
                setSetting();
                var execAjax = $.ajax(settings);
            }
        }

        function setSetting() {
            settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": url,
                "method": ajaxMethod,
                "dataType": "json",
                "complete": function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log("Completed: " + textStatus);
                },
                "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                },
                "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    listarConsulta(data);
                    if (!doNotDisplay) {
                        apiCall();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function nextButton() {
            //set MAX
            if (page_num <= 999) {
                index_id_ref = 0;
                buttonClicked = true;
                //async = false; crossDomain = false;
                buttonEventFinished = false;

                apiFunction();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

After debugging I can see that the JS functions are working but when it finish it executes again the asp page, I think a postback is set to false, and the settings of the API functions are good but maybe I am wrong.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this. 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Call JS function in `OnClientClick` instead of `OnClick`:

```
OnClientClick="return nextButton();"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! But I decided to post it so that if someone have the same problem can have the solution. The code is working. It is important to write "return false;" to prevent postback if you want to execute an event that calls an Ajax function with an html element (not asp). This code worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ebldieg There is nothing to do with async property of xhr with page refreshing. however setting async to false is deffered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem Is that your button is of type 'submit'. So every time user clicks on the button it gets submitted, hence page get refreshed in your case. Try changing the button's type to 'button'.

```
<button type="button"></button>
```